# Get email and last name from contacts

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-contacts

I have used an intent of contact picker. I am getting the data of contact through the intent. By that that intent I am fetching the name, number of the contact person.

When I tried to fetch an email id of  contact it only shows the number of the contact instead of an email id. Also for last name of contact it shows always null though the last is been set to the contact.

Code:

```
 private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String name = null;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

        int contactIdIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);

        int emailIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA);

        int lastNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);


        mOrganizerPhone = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        mOraganizerName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        mOrganizersId = cursor.getString(contactIdIndex);
        mOrganizersEmail = cursor.getString(emailIndex);
        mOrganizersLastName = cursor.getString(lastNameIndex);


    Toast.makeText(PlanEventActivity.this,name+" "+phoneNo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Is anything wrong in my query?

How to get this? Thank you..

Comment: Is it the values you're displaying in your toast that you're saying are wrong? Looks like you're printing phoneNo and name there but those aren't where you've stored the email address and last name from your query.

Comment: no i am checking by debug values of string email and last name.@KarenForde

Comment: mOrganizersLastName and mOrganizersEmail?